# data type to use for an exception thrown by a validator?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I need to capture any exceptions thrown by the validator but I cannot figure out how to due it.  Here is the code I have tried:

```
internal static class XMLValidator
{
    public static void Validate(XElement elem)
    {            
        string xsdMarkup;

        using(var file = new StreamReader(Constants.Xsd))
        {               
            xsdMarkup = file.ReadToEnd();
        }       

        XmlSchemaSet schema = new XmlSchemaSet();
        bool valid = true;
        schema.Add(XmlSchema.Read(XElement.Parse(xsdMarkup).CreateReader(), (o, e) => { }));
        new XDocument(elem).Validate(schema, (o, e) => { valid = false; exception = e; });
        if (valid == false)
        {
            throw exception;               
        }
        valid = true;                          
    }
}
```

I get a "the name exception does not exist in current context" error.  I'm pretty sure that the problem is that I have not given exception a data type.  However I have no idea what type to use.

I tried adding var before the exception but then it's not recogonized inside of the if statement and of course var cannot be declared outside of a method

I then tried declaring exemption globally as a string and setting to e like this:

```
exception = e.ToString();
```

but then I can't throw it inside of the if statement.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: What type of application is this..is this a Console Application or WinForms Application.., etc..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delegate you're using creates an `XmlSchemaValidationException`:

```
    XmlSchemaValidationException exception = null;
    new XDocument(elem).Validate(schema, (o, e) => { valid = false; exception = e.Exception; });
    if (valid == false)
    {
        throw exception;               
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, in this particular case you probably want to create your own type of Exception to throw.

```
public class InvalidDataException : Exception
{ }
```

(There are times where it's appropriate to do something within the definition of the class, but in most cases you really don't need anything.)

Then you can do something like this:

```
throw new InvalidDataException("Error message goes here");
```

Or, you can find some existing type of exception to throw that is created by the standard library or what have you.